# Google Analytics Ecommerce Conversion Vs Referral

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I was able to implement the API for tracking Revenue in Google Analytics using the code below. How can I make it so in the report it will show that the revenue came from specific referrer? If the client came from www.foo.com before going to our website www.bar.com/order, I want to show that this order was from www.foo.com in our analytics reports dashboard. Any help is appreciated since I am new to Google Analytics.

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', '<account>', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('require', 'ecommerce');

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id': '1238',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
        'affiliation': 'MyCompany',   // Affiliation or store name.
        'revenue': '100',               // Grand Total.
        'shipping': '0',                  // Shipping.
        'tax': '0'                     // Tax.
      });
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id': '1238',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
        'name': 'Servers',    // Product name. Required.
        'sku': 'server',                 // SKU/code.
        'category': 'Server',         // Category or variation.
        'price': '100',                 // Unit price.
        'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
      });
     ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Comment: I have removed to API tag which seems to add nothing to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA does this by default (if properly implemented). Set source/medium as second dimension in your transaction report and you will see "referral" as the medium and the referring domain as source. There are a few ways to mess this up (e.g. manually adding campaign values which will overwrite the referrer) but if you do a vanilla GA installation you do not need to worry, GA will pick this up automatically.

Your domain (or multiple domains, if you do cross-domain tracking) must be included in the referral exclusion list in the property settings.

On the other hand if you want to set a referrer manually you can use the set method:

```
ga('set', 'referrer', 'http://example.com');
```

This must be placed after the "create" call and will affect all interactions (pageviews, events, ecommerce etc) that follow later (you can do this also in the configuration object for any interaction call, in that case only that call will be affected).

Comment: is there a way to implement setReferrerOverride from my script above?

Comment: @helloworld2013 I edited my anwser to include an example for the current syntax to set a referrer manually.

Comment: thanks @Eike Pierstorff , I will try this solution, my issue was our clients may click on different pages on our site that may cause the referrer to be the website itself, any suggestion about this is welcome.

Comment: Is your domain included in the referral exclusion list (should be by default, but check this to be on the safe side) - this is in the property settings (added this to the answer, too).